# iOS: Render a purely pixel-based fractal effect using OpenGL ES?

Tags: ios, objective-c, graphics, opengl-es, shader

I am new to Objective-C and OpenGL, so please be patient.

I'm building an app that is mainly based on a full-screen 2D pixelbuffer that is filled and animated using mathematical formulas (similar to fractals), mostly using sin, cos, atan etc.

I have already optimized sin and cos by using tables which gave quite an fps boost, however, while the framerate is cool in the Simulator on a Mac Mini (around 30 fps), I get a totally ridiculous 5 fps on an actual device (iPad Mini non-retina).

As I see no further ways to optimize the pixel loops, would it be possible to implement the effects using, say, an OpenGL shader, and then just draw a fullscreen quad with a texture on it?

As I said, the effects are really simple and just iterate over all pixels in a nested x/y loop and use basic math and trig functions. The way I blit to the screen is already optimal for the device while staying in non-OpenGL, and gives like a million FPS if I leave out the actual math.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you implement this as a OpenGL shader you will get a *rediculously massive* increase in performance.  The shader would run on the graphics chip, which is designed to be massively parallel, and is optimized exactly for this kind of math.

You don't make a texture so much as define a shader for the surface.  Your shader code would be invoked for every rendered pixel on that surface.

I would start by trying to see if you can hack a shader here: http://glsl.heroku.com/

Once you have something working, you can research how to get an OpenGL context working with your shader on iOS, and you shouldn't have to change the actual shader much to get it working.

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking for guidance if my assumption was right and  an OpenGL shader would be the right tool for the job. Now, you don't happen to know if there's some kind of OpenGL ES template that will give me just a fullscreen quad whose texture is rendered by a shader and updated on each frame? It would be a bit over the top for me to learn the entirety of OpenGL ES just for this single task (I won't be doing any 3D stuff any time soon).

Comment: Yeah not sure, I've never done this on iOS :) But the shader should be _mostly_ portable, which is why I recommend twiddling around with the link above since it's zero setup, only shader.  I'm sure you can find an iOS project template somewhere on GitHub that gives you a shader canvas though.

Comment: @user1364098 - My [GPUImage framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) renders full-frame quads using shaders for video and image processing effects, and abstracts away the OpenGL ES required there. You just provide the fragment shader (and vertex shader, if necessary). You could rig this to operate only over a single still frame to generate your fractal. I'd also suggest grabbing Apple's [GLSL Showpiece example](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/samplecode/GLSLShowpiece/Introduction/Intro.html), which implements a fractal shader from the Orange Book.